# how to run an Ignored test (Parameterized and ignored at class level) with Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, junit4

I have set of "Parameterized" tests with @Ignored attention at class level. Looks like gradle does not detect the tests at all.   How can I run these tests from command line?  Here is sample test code

`gradle tests --tests some.bad.tests.ThisTestIsAnIgnoredTest`

```
import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;


@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@Ignore
public class TestNumbers4IgnoredAtClassLevelParameterizedTest {
    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
                {"data1",},
                {"data2"},

        });
    }

    private String data;

    @Test
    public void ignoredInJunit4() {
        System.out.println(new Numbers().add(1,2));
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}
```

Command running test

```
 $CHS_HOME/bld/gradle/bin/gradle test --tests TestNumbers4IgnoredAtClassLevelParameterizedTest --info
```

Result

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> No tests found for given includes: [TestNumbers4IgnoredAtClassLevelParameterizedTest](--tests filter)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

All works fine if I move the @Ignore from class to method level.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you probably can't - I don't know about JUnit's internals but https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html says:

> In order to operate, the Test task type requires just two pieces of
> information:
>
> - Where to find the compiled test classes (property:
>   Test.getTestClassesDirs())
> - The execution classpath, which should include the classes under test
>   as well as the test library that you’re using (property:
>   Test.getClasspath())

So it is likely that JUnit is simply not compiling the @Ignore'd methods, as there is no configuration around which tests get run or not.